# k6: how to send post request with empty request body, content-type 'application/json' and content-length 0?

Tags: k6

I'm trying to send a post request using k6's http.post. It needs to have an empty request body (content length 0) and `Content-Type: 'application/json'`.

I tried

```
let res = http.post(url, {}, {
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  });
```

and

```
let res = http.post(url, null, {
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  });
```

and

```
let res = http.post(url, "", {
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  });
```

In all cases I got a 411 response because no content length was set. I was expecting the content length to be set to 0.

The only way I can get the request to be sent is to wrap the empty request body in `JSON.stringify`, e.g.

```
  let res = http.post(url, JSON.stringify({}), {
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  });
```

But this means content length of 2, rather than 0. Is there a more correct / idiomatic way to send the empty body?

Comment: Is the header mandatory? Sending an empty body without the header should work. (And I tried it, it looks like k6 does send content-length:0, even if specified manually)

Comment: A missing payload seems to set the `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header. I suspect a k6 bug here – or at least somewhat confusing/intransparent behavior